# how to fix Javac invalid flag error?

Tags: applet, javac

I am trying to compile a an STK applet.

Firstly, I would like to compile the `.java` class by using `javac`. I am getting an error (invalid flag); this is my command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin>javac C:\Users\user\Desktop\ImsiManager Applet\2014-07-34_ImsiManager_src\2014-07-34_ImsiManager_src\ImsiManager\src\main\java\com\simulity\javacard\imsimanager\ImsiManager.java
Javac: invalid flag: C:\Users\user\Desktop\ImsiManager
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem are the spaces, you should enclose it with quotes:

```
javac "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ImsiManager Applet\2014-07-34_ImsiManager_src\2014-07-34_ImsiManager_src\ImsiManager\src\main\java\com\simulity\javacard\imsimanager\ImsiManager.java"
```

Answer (score 0):

change your jdk version to upper version in your IDE and your project config